# Correct way to do Tailwind grids?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I am just getting started using Tailwind and I am a bit confused on how to use grids/rows and columns correctly. Here are the different methods I see being used...

Method 1:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-1">
  <div class="my-1 px-1 w-1/2">
    <!-- Column Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="my-1 px-1 w-1/2">
    <!-- Column Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Method 2:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1">
  <div>
    <!-- Column Content -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Column Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Method 3:

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col gap-1">
  <div class="col-span-1">
    <!-- Column Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-1">
    <!-- Column Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone explain to me the difference between these 3 methods and which one is the correct one to use for what application?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! This question will get a bunch of opinions - since there is no "correct" use. The main difference is the first example is using the `flexbox` model and the second and third are using CSS Grid. For all the child classes, you can look at the Tailwind documentation to understand what those do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's discuss each example. As mentioned in the comments, there's no way to create a "perfect" grid, nor there's a way to create the "best" grid. Everything depends on what you're going to create.

The first example you mentioned is built using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

The second and the third examples are built using [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

#### The first example:

The `flex` class will cause the div element to be a **flex container**.

`flex-wrap` will control how flex items wrap.

`-mx-1` is a [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property which will control the element's margin, where it's exactly equal:

```css
margin-left: -0.25rem;
margin-right: -0.25rem;
```

In the second div, the `my-1` is a margin property, too, where it's exactly equal:

```css
margin-top: 0.25rem;
margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
```

`px-1` is a [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) property, which will control the element's padding, where it's exactly equal:

```css
padding-left: 0.25rem;
padding-right: 0.25rem;
```

`w-1/2` is a width property, which will set the element's width, where it's exactly equal:

```css
width: 50%;
```

#### The second example:

The `grid` class will cause the div element to be a **grid layout**.

`grid-cols-2` will specify the columns in the grid layout, where it's exactly equal:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
```

`gap-1` will control gutters between grid and flexbox items, where it's exactly equal:

```css
gap: 0.25rem;
```

#### The third example:

The third example is somewhat similar to the second one, but I'll explain the other classes that aren't mentioned above.

`grid-flow-col` is a Grid Auto Flow property, which will control how elements in a grid are auto-placed.

`col-span-1` will control how elements are sized and placed across grid columns, where it's exactly equal:

```css
grid-column: span 1 / span 1;
```